# Handling SOAP Fault in Spring Boot WebServiceTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I am new to SOAP, trying to run a sample SOAP client using Spring Boot

How the SOAP fault, Exceptions or Errors are handled while using  WebServiceTemplate

```
 public class CountryClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CountryClient.class);

  public GetCountryResponse getCountry(String country) {

    GetCountryRequest request = new GetCountryRequest();
    request.setName(country);

    log.info("Requesting location for " + country);

    GetCountryResponse response = (GetCountryResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
        .marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8080/ws/countries", request,
            new SoapActionCallback(
                "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service/GetCountryRequest"));

    return response;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

One way is writing your custom interceptor which implements Spring WS's ClientInterceptor interface. You should override handleFault method to handle SOAP faults with your custom logic.

```
public class MySoapClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySoapClientInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {

        LOGGER.info("intercepted a fault...");
        SoapBody soapBody = getSoapBody(messageContext);
        SoapFault soapFault = soapBody.getFault();
        LOGGER.error(soapFault.getFaultStringOrReason());
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Error occured while invoking SOAP service - %s ", soapFault.getFaultStringOrReason()));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex) throws WebServiceClientException {

    }

    private SoapBody getSoapBody(MessageContext messageContext) {
        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        SoapEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getEnvelope();
        return soapEnvelope.getBody();
    }
}
```

Then you need to register your custom Interceptor class as an interceptor at your SOAP client config class. At the bean definition of CountryClient at your Configuration class in your case.

```
@Configuration
public class SoapClientConfig {

    @Value("${soap.server.url}")
    public String soap_server_url;

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SoapConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SoapConnector client = new SoapConnector();
        client.setDefaultUri(soap_server_url);
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        ClientInterceptor[] clientInterceptors = {new MySoapClientInterceptor()};
        client.setInterceptors(clientInterceptors);
        return client;
    }

}
```